# pandas filter using combinations of boolean series

Tags: python, pandas

I have 7 boolean series of equal length:

```
msk_valid_structure
msk_submission_context
msk_reference_substance_location
msk_neutral
msk_identifier_origin
msk_two_conversion_methods
msk_no_error_warnings
```

I need to combine them with a logical AND (&) and so that:

- we always include the first one (msk_valid_structure)
- we include 5 out of 6 of the remaining ones (all combinations)

I tried two solutions and I am not happy with neither.

The first one uses reduce and it is quite slow:

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
for combination in combinations(msks, 5):
    res = reduce(lambda x,y: x&y, combination, msk_valid_structure)
```

The second one constructs dataframes that is also slow:

```
from itertools import combinations
for combination in combinations(msks, 5):
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({i: col for i, col in enumerate(list(combination) + [msk_valid_structure])})
    res = tmp.all(axis='columns')
```

How would you handle this situation?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: usually creation and/or appending of larger DataFrames within a loop would be prohibitively slow. how about creating a basic Python data structure then loading that all in to a final DataFrame outside of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a DataFrame from your series and then use apply. Here you can write your custom function to add a column with the result valid/invalid or you directly do something if the condition is fulfilled.

This way has the benefit, that its vectorized and kinda fast compared to looping

With:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating dataframe
test=[[0,   0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1],
      [1,   0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1],
      [0,   1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
      [1,   1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1]]

cols = ['msk_valid_structure',
        'msk_submission_context',
        'msk_reference_substance_location',
        'msk_neutral',
        'msk_identifier_origin',
        'msk_two_conversion_methods',
        'msk_no_error_warnings']

df_test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=cols)

# Defining function matching your condition
def your_func(s: pd.Series):
    valid_stucture = s.msk_valid_structure
    # Because any combination, i just summed Trues
    # if you only allow specific combinations just write conditions here with .col or ['col'] notation
    rest = s.iloc[1:].sum()
    if valid_stucture and (rest >= 5):
        return 1
    return 0

# Applying the function and saving results in foo
df_test['foo'] = df_test.apply(lambda x: your_func(x), axis=1)

# Result of foo:
0,0,0,1
```